# Need to read the last value from an output of n numbers

Tags: java

I have a part of a program which looks like this.

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
   Random t = new Random();

// random integers in [0, 100]
  System.out.println(t.nextInt(100));
}
```

I need to redirect just the last value to a text file. Any way I can print just the last value on the console? The very last value and nothing else.

Comment: Well, one solution:
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
   if (i < 49) continue;
   Random ...
   Print...
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More importantly, you **must not** create a new `Random` instance on each iteration. That completely ruins the statistical properties of the generator.

To print out the last value, store it and print at the end.

Putting this all together:

```
{ /*To stop t and n leaking into scope*/
    Random t = new Random();
    int n = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 50; ++i){ /*I prefer ++i as I'm an old-fashioned cat*/
        n = t.nextInt(100); /*presumably you do something with this number*/
    }
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: Good point, completely missed `Random` being instantiated each iteration. +1

Comment: Feel free to add that warning to your answer.

Comment: Yep. My bad. Creating instances of t inside that loop is foolishness. And this worked for me. So yay. 4 more minutes until I can select this as the best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(i == 49){
   System.out.println(t.nextInt(100));
}
```

Will only print the digit on the 50th iteration, when `i = 49`. That's all your question seems to ask for. Obviously that has to be placed within the for-loop. You can adjust the condition within the if-statement to fit your desired behaviour.

Also as it has already been pointed out. You ought to instantiate `Random t` only once and that's outside the for-loop. This way you don't *break* the randomness of the algorithm and you don't unnecessarily instantiate the object multiple times.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, agree - creating instances of t over every single iteration is foolishness.

Comment: No worries, we've all done that *(and far worse but refuse to admit it haha)*. Glad the answer helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable above the for block and initialize it every time when the loop runs and use it after the for loop finishes:

```
Random t = null;
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
   t = new Random();
   // random integers in [0, 100]
   System.out.println(t.nextInt(100));
}
if (t != null) {
    // do write operation to text file here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the index, try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
  Random t = new Random();

   // random integers in [0, 100]
   if(i==49) {
     System.out.println(t.nextInt(100));
   }
}
```

Comment: wow down vote on a correct but not perfect answer. Amazing :)

Comment: looks fine to me... bumped you back up to 0 ;)

Comment: The answer was exactly as the one above you, it was redundant and posted minutes after the first one was posted.

Comment: Thanks starvator:) @Juxhin when the answer is posted when I'm writing mine, how on earth could I know... By the way, in your answer you say when `i=50`, which is wrong, even though your code segment is correct. No down vote from me though!

Answer (score 0):

```
int last = -1;

for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
    Random t = new Random();

    // random integers in [0, 100]
    last = t.nextInt(100);
    //System.out.println(last);
}

// Now take "last" and do whatever you want with it.
doSomething(last);
```

Comment: This does not "redirect the value."

Comment: Sorry if I didn't read your question carefully. I've edited my response. Does commenting out that System.out.println make it okay?

Comment: Ah! Anyway, everyone but that one guy missed the fact that Random was being re-instantiated with each iteration of the loop. Good luck with what you're doing!